# dash app not working when deployed in AWS ECS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, plotly-dash

I deployed a dash app in aws ecs. Everything works fine  and the task seems to be running.

[image]

[image]

However when i try to use the public or private ip on the port that the app is running (10000), it is not working. Any idea why it could be happening?

[image]

My port:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you don't have port `10000` open in the security group.

Comment: Apologies, i am very new. How do i check this?

Comment: Go look at the inbound rules of the security group you have assigned to your ECS task.

Comment: Yes i've set it in 10000 and still  not working.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, managed to work it out?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have accepted inbound rules for your current IP for port 10000.

Comment: Yes' I've already done that..